# Prevent data insert in mandatory column

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

I am newbie in oracle database. I have three tables:[image]

Now i am going to insert data in Event according to event type.
but if i have event type "Vacations" or "sick leave" which does not contain any region. In this case how the data will be populated in Event table.

Region table is connected with it because of event type "Business Trip".

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it makes sense not to have any region associated with it then just use `NULL` as the foreign key values:

```
INSERT INTO Event ( ID, Event_Type, User_ID, Start_Trip, End_Trip, Start_Date, End_Date )
VALUES            ( 1, 'Sick Leave', 1, NULL, NULL, DATE '2016-02-29', DATE '2016-03-31' );
```

In which case the `Start_Trip` and `End_Trip` column should be nullable - if this is an issue then you can convert the `NOT NULL` constraint on those columns to a `CHECK` constraint. I.e.

```
CHECK ( ( UPPER( Event_Type ) IN ( 'SICK LEAVE', 'VACATION' )
          AND Start_Trip IS NULL
          AND End_Trip IS NULL )
      OR
        ( UPPER( Event_Type ) NOT IN ( 'SICK LEAVE', 'VACATION' )
          AND Start_Trip IS NOT NULL
          AND End_Trip IS NOT NULL )
      )
```

This does then bring up issues of maintaining the data if another event type is added that should be null in which case a developer will have to modify the table constraints. (Which could be solved by having a table of event types which contains details of whether the region is `NULL` or not and then using this as a foreign key within the `Event` table.)

If it makes sense to have a region (i.e. if the user is sick or on leave then that could be associated with their home region) then use the appropriate region ID:

```
INSERT INTO Event ( ID, Event_Type, User_ID, Start_Trip, End_Trip, Start_Date, End_Date )
SELECT 1, 'Sick Leave', ID, Region_Id, Region_Id, DATE '2016-02-29', DATE '2016-03-31'
FROM   PT_USER
WHERE  ID = 1; -- The user's ID
```

Which choice you should make should be determined by your business logic (we can't help you with that).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed the relation between Region and Event from mandatory to optional and now i can use Region table with nullable values start and end trip.